# Can I request all Pandas columns display in an IPython notebook?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

By default, the number of columns displayed by `pandas` commands is limited to `display.max_columns`. Is there something like `df.showall()` that can be used to override this on a per-command bases?

Comment: Depends on your version in the past `df.to_string` would output everything but otherwise in 0.13.1 you'd have to do `df.values` which is not quite the same

Comment: You could do `df.info(max_cols=1000)` I just looked this up

Comment: @EdChum: That just works for `info`. I'm looking for a way to request to see all columns of a dataframe of series.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I have found to do this is the following:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML(df.to_html())
```

This will display the whole table in the IPython notebook output cell - all rows and columns.  Scrollbars will appear for large tables.

To display all columns but no more than `N` rows, use:

```
HTML(df.head(N).to_html())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a context manager:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def temp_option(option, value):
    old_value = pd.get_option(option)
    pd.set_option(option, value)
    yield
    pd.set_option(option, old_value)
```

Then do what you want, something like

```
>>>with temp_option('display.max_rows', 200):
        print(df)
```

I thought pandas already had this feature, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Nice approach. But nothing in `pandas`; too bad.

Comment: Like I said, I think there is something like this. But I couldn't find it. By the way, if you're using the IPython notebook you may want to import the `display` function from `IPython.display` (instead of print) to get the html repr of the DataFrame.

Comment: try pd.option_context (new in 0.13.1)

Comment: @Jeff: That might be an answer.